# PDF image files and `htlatex`: Problem

Tags: tex4ht, htlatex

I branch from "PDF image files and `htlatex`" as advised by michal.h21.

I use myxhtml.cfg as follows

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\makeatletter
\Configure{graphics*}  
  {pdf}  
  {
    \Needs{"convert      \csname Gin@base\endcsname.pdf  
                         \csname Gin@base\endcsname.png"}%  
    \Picture[pict]      {\csname Gin@base\endcsname.png}%  
    \special{t4ht+@File: \csname Gin@base\endcsname.png}
  }
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

Then  test.tex

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[dvips]{xcolor}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage[tex4ht]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{picture}(0,0)% 
\includegraphics{1fig2dev.pdf}% 
\end{picture}% 
\end{document}
```

and  pdf file 1fig2dev.pdf is quite small

```
%PDF-1.5
%Çì¢
5 0 obj
>
stream
x­S»R^C1^Lìý^UªS^HKgëñ^EÔ   ^E^_¤H      ^Tü>ò½^RrÇ^LEæ
¥´ëµ/ ·o\÷çô´S8|¥KÊ@Y2SK^R³Ýüô©S:&Ò¬(^E:,^BNjJAá^Z(R¤^A©£gi^Qñ^NÕ^Cc¨äë^QUBV jQ\úÈïYmþë^F>^Rc×&}÷T3ì^S^G^GaR:4­A«@^E+g^T30«(ÊP      ­zôä@y»OTX0Ì^@áU¢^PU¼^X­èÖâØ^Eñ}zIÛ pX=^U¹÷âÞ7+Â^^Õü^XtÿíñØÏã,\|Ù;êQmðxpÝ«`^V¹é^X¯Á"00÷^RgìtÃ|tuxôS¢ýÞ:Fåä&å\yrsÚ^Ý^A£PhvÓ»¸¢.£«Âï)/T-4^OêÔ\B^Aukâ^T+^S÷oíóm^Bã^_éÒ¦±
Ù¦^_¸´Î!endstream
endobj
6 0 obj
352
endobj
4 0 obj
>
/Contents 5 0 R
>>
endobj
3 0 obj
>
endobj
1 0 obj
>
endobj
7 0 obj
>endobj
8 0 obj
>
endobj
9 0 obj
>stream





2016-10-17T21:01:33+02:00
2016-10-17T21:01:33+02:00
fig2dev Version 3.2 Patchlevel 5e

1fig2dev.fig




endstream
endobj
2 0 obj
>endobj
xref
0 10
0000000000 65535 f 
0000000646 00000 n 
0000002219 00000 n 
0000000587 00000 n 
0000000456 00000 n 
0000000015 00000 n 
0000000437 00000 n 
0000000710 00000 n 
0000000751 00000 n 
0000000780 00000 n 
trailer
]
>>
startxref
2407
%%EOF
```

all residing in the same folder.

Now i type htlatex test.tex myxhtml but this does not work:

```
! LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in 1fig2dev.pdf (no BoundingBox
).

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H   for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.7 \includegraphics{1fig2dev.pdf}
```

It seems as if the pdf is not replaced. 
I tried convert 1fig2dev.pdf 1fig2dev.png manually and verified with gwenview 1fig2dev.png... seems to be fine.

What went wrong????

ok, partial answer: 
The problem disappears if i remove the picture environment. 
Is this a bug in htlatex????

Comment: Please post a full question.

Comment: should be ok now, sorry

Answer (score 1):

contents of `picture` environment is converted to image using some `dvi` to image converter. `tex4ht` configurations are suppressed inside it, so the configuration for `graphics*` in not executed at all, the PDF file is inserted as it is. If you try to run your document with `latex`, you would get exactly the same error.

If you move the `\includegraphics` outside the `picture` environment, the `graphics*` configuration will take an effect and the PDF picture will be included. If you really want to include image in the `picture` environment, you need to use `eps` format, which is supported in the DVI mode.

I would use following method:

Prepare the images in all needed formats (pdf, png, eps), declare which extensions should LaTeX use in particular mode, remove extensions from `\includegraphics` command and let LaTeX decide which one it should use.

You modified document:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[]{xcolor}
\usepackage[]{graphicx}
\usepackage[tex4ht]{hyperref}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{pdf,png,jpg}
\begin{document}
\begin{picture}(0,0)% 
\includegraphics{1fig2dev}% 
\end{picture}% 

\includegraphics{1fig2dev}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, `\DeclareGraphicsExtensions` command is used to define extensions, which should be tried when image is included. These will be used in the PDF mode. Now you need to modify the `.cfg` file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Configure{picture}
{\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps}\Picture+[PICT]{}}
{\EndPicture}
\begin{document}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.png,.jpg,.gif}

\EndPreamble
```

`\Configure{picture}` is used to declare that `eps` images should be used inside `picture` environment, `png`,`jpg` or `gif` should be used otherwise.